# Migrating Eclipse Google cloud endpoints project to version 2

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have a java app engine project with cloud endpoints created with google plugin for eclipse. Now I'm trying to migrate the project to use endpoints version 2. I have installed java 8, eclipse 4.6 and Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin, then imported the old project and converted it to Standard app engine project.

1. Their migration guide ask to edit maven or gradle files. I don't have any of those files. It is just an eclipse project.
2. Anyway I can build and run the project. But when I access any endpoint method it gives an error: Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 500

Full error log:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 500
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.getApiConfigSources(ApiServlet.java:104)
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.initConfigsIfNecessary(ApiServlet.java:69)
at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:114)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)...
```

Anybody know how to properly migrate this?